# system Update failure

Tags: updates, system

I have latest version — juno which used to bring frequent notifications for update and used to get updated easily but for the last 3 weeks it has stopped sending notifications and doesn't get updated at all and is showing a cogwheel item in dock as well which doesn't show any description on hovering mouse on. Already tried `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade` but doesn't work.

any idea about fixing this issue?

Comment: Can you please update the question with the output when you try updating from terminal?

Answer (score 0):

So i worked it out by using following commands;

```
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

so thanks for your help, probably it was broken repository which was cause of trouble